# BTRFS partition will not mount after power off

Tags: fedora, filesystems, data-recovery, btrfs

I'm running Fedora 38 on a BTRFS partition and just had to do a hard power off due to system hang.  Now the system goes into emergency mode on bootup.  I'm currently running the fedora live CD but the main system partition refuses to mount. When doing so through the GUI it says:

Error mounting /dev/nvme0n1p8 at /run/media/liveuser/8ae5f957-a101-4486-991d-36558ce61b24: mount(2) system call failed: File exists

I ran btrfs check and it reported no errors.

Any ideas please? Thank you very much for any help.  I will restart now and try to get the exact error from the emergency mode, although I don't think it gave any useful info.

Answer (score 0):

So I was wrong, the startup log led me to the answer.  Here's the relevant bit for any future googlers:

BTRFS: error (device nvme0n1p8: state A) in __btrfs_run_delayed_items:1158: errno=-17 Object already exists
BTRFS: error (device nvme0n1p8: state EA) in btrfs_replay_log:2482: errno=-17 Object already exists (Failed to recover log tree)

Ran this command in terminal:

sudo btrfs rescue zero-log /dev/mapper/nvme0n1p8

Hey presto, fixed.